# Render HTML element in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a variable in javascript which is defined like

```
var tip = "<p style="color:red;">This is tip</p>";
```

I am assigning this tip into a `<div>` element of my page. But that div is displaying text same as above. I want this to come in red color and with other styles which I add to this later.

Comment: Firstly I don't see how this can work at all considering you have a syntax error with the mismatched quotes. Secondly, there's no question here. What is the problem, and what is your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `html()` instead of `text()` like:

```js
var tip = '<p style="color:red;">This is tip</p>';
$('body').append(tip);
// $('#selector').html(tip);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Explanation:** When you want to pass some string as text then use `text()` and when you want to pass it as html use `html()`.

Comment: Yes. But I have this variable in my angular controller and I am using this syntax to render this in view.

    <div>{{tip}}</div>

In this case how can I achieve my goal.

Comment: @Alex: If you are using `angular` then why don't you tag it in your question?

Comment: Yes I should. But I thought that mainly this is a javascript issue.

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery is a bit much here, but usually simple for a start

```js
//learn about escaping
var tip = "<p style=\"color:red;\">This is tip</p>";
//also: var tip = "<p style='color:red;'>This is tip</p>";
//or:  var tip = '<p style="color:red;">This is tip</p>';

//set html content is simple with jQuery:
//$('#target').html( tip );
//same as simple JavaScript:
document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = tip;
```

```css
#target{
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- this you do not need when not using jquery, would quite some bandwidth; also think about hosting those files yourself if you need them and do not rely on third parties for data security reasons and availability of service -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">empty</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you need to learn how to generate or create dom elements using javascript or jquery

you can also create it using javascript, but jquery made it easy!!

```js
var $p = $("<p>");
$p.css("color","red");
$p.html("This is tip.");
$('body').append($p);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one:

```
var tip = "<p>This is tip</p>";
$('youdiv').html(tip).css('color','red');
```

You can also try this one:

```
var tip = "<p style='color:red;'>This is tip</p>";
$('youdiv').html(tip);
```

Comment: please edit with formatted code and give explanation of why OP should do this EDIT: FYI did not DV